# Find all matching criteria where conditions not in array

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I am trying to return a variable with values of an array of users. There are a few conditions that must be met. The user must have `public_find` set to `true`, it must not be the `current_user` (session variable of the user currently logged in), and it must not already be part of a friendship. The first and second conditions work perfectly. However, I am having an issue with the third part where the `current_users.friendships` needs to be an array of the `ID` values of the users where the association already exists. Any thoughts?

```
@users = User.find(:all, :conditions => ['
    public_find=true AND 
    id <> ? AND 
    id NOT IN (?)',
    current_user.id, current_user.friendships])
```

Edit:

I've figured out that I was missing pluck from the list. This works good now. However, if someone does not yet have a friend then `current_user.friendships.pluck(:friend_id)` will return `NULL`. I know that it is bad practice and unexpected results returned when using `NOT IN` and `NULL`. However, how do you create a condition where you can set the value to something realistic like [0] or [1] if the array returned is empty?

```
@users = User.find(:all, :conditions => ['
    public_find=true AND 
    id <> ? AND 
    id NOT IN (?)',
    current_user.id, current_user.friendships.pluck(:friend_id) || [0]])
```

EDIT AGAIN:

I got it working. However, now I want to know if this is best practice to have a statement like this. It basically is doing a check to see if the `current_user.friendships.pluck(:friend_id)` is empty or not. If it is then return [0]. Otherwise return an array of the user ids (foreign keyed as `friend_id`).

```
@users = User.find(:all, :conditions => ['
    public_find=true AND 
    id <> ? AND 
    id NOT IN (?)',
    current_user.id, 
    (current_user.friendships.pluck(:friend_id).empty? ? [0] : current_user.friendships.pluck(:friend_id))])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write this a little nicer ..

Show all users where public_find is true and also exclude the currently logged in user or any of their friends

```
ids = current_user.friendships.map(&:friend_id).concat([current_user.id])
@users = User.where(:public_find => true).where('id not in ?', ids)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use an arel table for this (which guarantees the code will work on any database):

```
t, f = User.arel_table, current_user.friendships
query = t[:public_find].eq(true).and(t[:id].not_eq(current_user.id))
query = query.and(t[:id].not_in(f.pluck(:friend_id))) unless f.empty?
@users = User.where(query)
```

Generated SQL for `current_user = 3` and a single friendship with a user with `id = 1`:

```
SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
WHERE ("users"."public_find" = 't' AND "users"."id" != 3 AND "users"."id" NOT IN (1))
```

If `current_user.friendships` is `nil`, the `unless f.empty?` clause will prevent that condition from being applied at all, so it will not appear in the SQL:

```
SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
WHERE ("users"."public_find" = 't' AND "users"."id" != 3)
```

Also, note that because this code uses `where` instead of `find`, the final result is an `ActiveRecord::Relation` rather than an array of results. This means that you can further chain conditions onto it, e.g. to order the results by `updated_at`, change the last line to:

```
@users = User.where(query).order(:created_at)
```